# Postgres replace function with an array of values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, replace

Is there a way to use an input array of values as a way to replace different string occurrences in one go?

Say we have an `input` array of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and a `replacement` array of `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.
Now if we were to do something like:

```
UPDATE table SET field=replace('a string to be replaced', input, replacement)
```

every `a` would get replaced with whatever is on the same index of `replacement` ('1'), every `b` replaced with the same index of `replacement` ('2'), etc, so `field` would then become `'1 string to 2e repl12e4'`.

(Using Postgres 9.4)

**EDIT:**

Another example, `input` is `['string', 'replaced']`, `replacement` is `['cat', 'dog']`, `field` would become `'a cat to be dog'`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html `array_replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural approach to this type of tasks is to use a loop inside a custom function:

```sql
create or replace function multireplace_loop
    (string text, pattern text[], replacement text[])
returns text language plpgsql immutable as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select ord, old_str, new_str
        from unnest(pattern, replacement) 
        with ordinality as o(old_str, new_str, ord)
        order by ord
    loop
        string:= replace(string, rec.old_str, rec.new_str);
    end loop;
    return string;
end $$;

select multireplace_loop
    ('a string to be replaced', '{string, replaced}', '{cat, dog}');
```

There is an elegant pure SQL alternative solution applying recursive query:

```sql
create or replace function multireplace_recursive
    (string text, pattern text[], replacement text[])
returns text language sql immutable as $$
    with recursive input_rows as (
        select ord, old_str, new_str
        from unnest(pattern, replacement) 
        with ordinality as o(old_str, new_str, ord)
    ),
    recursive_replace as (
        select ord, replace(string, old_str, new_str) as string
        from input_rows
        where ord = 1
    union all
        select i.ord, replace(string, i.old_str, i.new_str)
        from recursive_replace r
        join input_rows i on i.ord = r.ord+ 1
    )
    select string
    from recursive_replace
    order by ord desc
    limit 1
$$;

select multireplace_recursive
    ('a string to be replaced', '{string, replaced}', '{cat, dog}');
```

Test it in [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=05f4c0ec6da2e10b9cf9c19e1ab5164a)

Comment: what if it's an input array with n-length strings?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Note, that while the recursive query may be more pleasant, the iteration approach should be significantly faster.